# How to add query with 2 parameters

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame is below `online_rt`

```
InvoiceNo   StockCode   Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice   CustomerID  Country
141 C536379 D   Discount    -1  12/1/10 9:41    27.50   14527.0 United Kingdom
154 C536383 35004C  SET OF 3 COLOURED FLYING DUCKS  -1  12/1/10 9:49    4.65    15311.0 United Kingdom
235 C536391 22556   PLASTERS IN TIN CIRCUS PARADE   -12 12/1/10 10:24   1.65    17548.0 United Kingdom
236 C536391 21984   PACK OF 12 PINK PAISLEY TISSUES -24 12/1/10 10:24   0.29    17548.0 United Kingdom
237 C536391 21983   PACK OF 12 BLUE PAISLEY TISSUES -24 12/1/10 10:24   0.29    17548.0 Hong Kong
```

need to find the parameters where `Quantity` is negative and `country=Hong Kong`

`online_rt.query('Quantity < 0' )`

i need to add one more parameter

`online_rt.query('Quantity < 0' and 'country=Hong Kong')` thrown error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with `'Hong Kong'` :

```
online_rt = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity':[-1,2,0],
                          'country':['Hong Kong','USA','Hong Kong']})

filtered_df = online_rt.query("Quantity < 0 & country == 'Hong Kong'")
print (filtered_df)
   Quantity    country
0        -1  Hong Kong
```

Another solution with `and` working in `query` like `&`:

```
filtered_df = online_rt.query("Quantity < 0 and country == 'Hong Kong'")
print (filtered_df)
   Quantity    country
0        -1  Hong Kong
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `online_rt` is a pandas DataFrame, you can use:

```
filtered_df = online_rt[(online_rt['Quantity']<0) & (online_rt['country']=='Hong Kong')]
```

Comment: can we use query method here?

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this

```
online_rt.query('Quantity < 0 & country == Hong Kong')
```